Is result of abstract function always the same if operation is repeated?
I'm working on my understanding of math. When reading about group (wikipedia) I thought: might binary operation give different results for same "input"? I've moved by links to other wiki pages: Binary_operation, Map, Function.
Nowhere I've found clear indication about the opposite, only e.g.:

In mathematics, a function from a set X to a set Y assigns to each
element of X exactly one element of Y.

So one element, but why not assign different (e.g. alternating) ones if repeated? Different results for different order of operations is known in math (hence notion of associativity).
E.g. for "group", it might be set of integers but with addition modified as if operands are neither 0 nor inverse of each other, the "addition" will alternate between adding 1 to and subtracting it from a "classical" result.
I wonder if such structures in algebra/other math are used, how they are called.
I guess most mathematicians expect a function to give same result for same input. How is it ensured (if defined) properly in the foundations of math?

For a broader perspective see referential transparency

In your example, what you are thinking of as the "operands" are not the only inputs into the calculation. There is also how many times the operation has been performed "before", or at least the parity of that count. Once you account for all the inputs, the operation becomes a mathematical function. Mathematics requires things to be well-defined. In order to reason, you have to know definitively how they behave.

The foundations of math are built on set theory; reading up more on that will get you a far way. Here's a summary of some notions which might help. I'm going to assume some idea of what a 'set' is; it's probably sufficient to think of a set as a collection of objects which is ''nice enough'' to not allow for paradoxes (such as the ''set'' of all sets not containing itself which, under our current paradigm, is not a set)
We define a function to be three things: A set called the domain, a set called the codomain, and a rule which assigns one element in the codomain to every element in the domain. There's some important things going on here that might help your understanding to unpack a little; if you feel like you have a good grasp of this, skip to "In a group..."
Firstly, we need to keep track of the domain and codomain; this is important for the function to be a function (to be 'well defined'). If we forget about the domain, we might wind up trying to apply a rule to an object which it doesn't make sense for  (trying to add five to a cat, for example). Perhaps more subtly, if we forget about the codomain, we might associate more than one thing to an object in the domain; for example, let's say that you have exactly one favorite book and exactly one favorite song. If I ask you to tell me your favorite book, you can do that - but if I ask you to tell me your favorite thing, you can't decide between your favorite book and your favorite song. This is because with the first question, I've specified the codomain of the function I care about (associating a person, you, to a book, your favorite book).
This discussion leads us right into the second thing that's important in our definition of a function - that it be well defined. This means that each object in the domain has one and only one object associated to it in the codomain. This is a required property of being a function - in fact, it's basically what we mean by function (note that, somewhat confusingly, this is a little bit different from, say, a function in computer programming - but that's another story).
In a group, what we have is a function with a very special domain; namely, the set $G\times G$ of pairs of elements $(g, f)$, such that $g$ and $f$ are both objects in $G$. What this means is that the operation in a group associates to each pair $(g, f)$ an object of $G$. It is absolutely true that this function will not be well-defined as a function from $G$ to $G$, unless we fix a choice of the first coordinate or the second coordinate.
It's important to note that (as Paul Sinclair noted so eloquently in his comment) this function cannot depend in any way on any information other than the input; in other words, your operation which 'alternates' would only be a function if you included, as an input, the number of times you've used that function before; if that was the case, it would probably be fairly difficult to make it into a group operation.
To answer your more general question about how mathematics deals with less 'well behaved' objects than functions, there are a few options. Firstly, as above, we can add more information to the domain (the 'input') of a function, or (alternatively) restrict the to not include certain things. This deals with many well-definiteness issues. Alternatively, there is the concept of a multi- valued function, which is a mathematical structure that generalizes a function to a relationship that can have multiple values for each value in the domain. Even more generally, a relation is just some method of associating some collection of elements in one set to some collection of elements in another, with no rules beyond that.
